# Swift/iOS Subview Not Showing Immediately, on Main Thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uiview, subview

So I'm adding several subviews to my ViewController's view in a loop; the problem is there's a ~5s delay for it in showing up from the time I add the subview. **I made sure to call setNeedsDisplay** on both the subview and my view after adding it, no dice. I even double-checked that the **code *is* executing on the main thread** using `NSThread.isMainThread()`, and it returned true as expected. Here's my exact code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "ProfileCard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        var profiles = self.delegate.user!.profilesToShow

        //loop to add ProfileCard subviews
        while profiles.count > 0 && self.deck.count < self.MAX_DECK_SIZE {
            println("Adding Card")

            //setup subview
            var card = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first! as ProfileCard
            card.delegate = self
            card.frame = CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.width - 300)/2, y: 100, width: 300, height: 200)
            card.displayProfile(profiles.first!)

            //add subview
            self.view.addSubview(card)
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(card)
            card.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

            //add card to deck, mark as shown
            self.deck.append(card)
            profiles.removeAtIndex(0)
        }
    }
```

Any print statements in this loop run about ~5s prior to the subview actually displaying, and I'm not sure what that's due to. I even set print statements in the init method of the subview, and even those printed with expected.

Comment: Where exactly is this code called from? Of what method is it an excerpt?

Comment: It's an excerpt from a method triggered via an NSNotification after a network request. The network request happens, this method is triggered, and the subviews are supposed to be created and added (which is what this code is). But this code runs, and then there's a delay before the subview shows up on screen.

Comment: So you've got other code called by the notification running on a background thread? Does _that_ code try to talk to the interface on the background thread? That could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Do you get all the `println`s in a big rush and then a delay and then all the drawing?

Comment: This is the entirety of the code called by the notification. I just got rid of the method signature for the sake of simplicity. Everything this code "talks to" is already loaded in memory, I believe.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I get :/ i.e. the network request happens -> notification method executes (code above) -> delay -> drawing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong-looking with the code you've shown. I'm convinced the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This* code may *not* be running on a background thread, but the fact that you have to come onto the main thread suggests that you have *other* code that *is* running on a background thread. That other code is the source of the problem. It is trying to talk to the interface on the background thread. That in turn is gumming up the whole drawing system.

Comment: I do, my network requests are happening on a separate thread. But as far as I can tell, there's no communication happening between this and the background thread. The only thing that comes from the background is the line `var profiles = self.delegate.user!.profilesToShow` where `profilesToShow` is an array populated by the separate thread. But that's why I made a temporary copy...  Hmmm :/

Comment: Also, if there were communication happening, would there be a delay just within the while loop itself? But it seems to all happen at once, and the drawing is the only thing delayed.

Comment: Drawing is a special process. No drawing happens while your code runs. Drawing takes place only after all your code has finished (when the CATransaction commits). Thus it is possible to gum up the _whole_ drawing system by trying to talk to it on a background thread.

Comment: Oh, and even making a copy (if that even _is_ a copy) you can have a clash of threads over `self.delegate.user!.profilesToShow`. That is not the way to communicate this data thread-safely down into the main thread.

Comment: Huh, interesting! Thanks for the tip! What would you suggest as an alternative way to communicate the data, that wouldn't screw with my threads? As far as I can tell, that's the only point of weakness...

Comment: What I would do is complete my networking and step out to the main thread then and there, so that _whenever_ I talk to `self.delegate.user!.profilesToShow` or any other property of `self` I am doing it on the main thread.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. I was trying to avoid this so I could work with part of the data, and keep loading more in the background. But I suppose I could alternatively load more as it's needed, though I'm afraid of that slowing it down.

Comment: Well you can step onto the main thread and do something and then step back onto a background thread. Just don't address the same space from two different threads. EVER.